# Three.js ShaderMaterial and multiple different textures

Tags: three.js

I have some models being loaded in that I want to all render using the same shader.

Since I have 100+ model chunks, each of which has its own texture, I would like to configure things in a way that I can reuse the same material for multiple Meshes. The problem, however, is that by assigning a texture, I have to do it to the material, that is to say the architecture seems to limit me from having a per-mesh texture without completely making a new Material for each of them.

So, everything still works, but the performance of a large scene composed of hundreds of meshes is problematic because of all of the looping state changes and calls being made to switch programs hundreds of times to render each frame. Of course, I should be making one big mesh instead of many little ones, as that'll help reduce actual number of draw calls... but for the time being I'm trying to optimize a little without addressing these issues arising from other parts of the data pipeline. The main issue is that regardless of how many draw calls are involved, all of the shader program changes and uniform assignments (aside from the texture sampler) are unnecessary.

Are there any tricks I can use or ways to easily hack the library to make it recycle the same shader? One of the problems is that due to the way assigning a texture works I do have to create a new ShaderMaterial for each of my Meshes. It's totally unclear how I could avoid doing such a thing and still get the different textures working.

Comment: It seems like you already know this but you should be using a [texture atlas](https://www.google.com/search?q=texture+atlas). Otherwise, yes, you have to create a new material for each thing. That's kind of the point. Materials are the settings for a shader. To pass different settings to a shader (eg, a different texture) you make a new set of settings, in other words, a Material

Comment: @gman I see what you're saying, but fundamentally there is a difference between the two approaches, in the one where i do not use my shadermaterial, things run faster... i'll take a look at the GL calls being made later but i'm pretty sure the reason is that a new shader *program* is being made per mesh with the shadermaterial, but for the meshbasicmaterial it will recycle the same program (there is only ever one program). So its comparing a texture uniform bind and one draw call per mesh with a shader program change, uniform binds including texture, and draw call per mesh.

Comment: So what i am asking is what would i need to do to make a shadermaterial that will recycle its shader like meshbasicmaterial does.